# How to install Ubuntu in a chroot environment on an Archlinux system?

Tags: chroot, debootstrap

Currently I'm stuck with an Archlinux system at work. However, I want to be able to package some software for Ubuntu on this machine. So I thought it should be possible to set up an Ubuntu (Precise) system inside a chroot environment on my Archlinux box. Of course, I wouldn't have X11 in the chroot, but I wouldn't need that.

Any thoughts on how I can install Ubuntu inside a chroot environment on my box?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I should've thought a bit more before asking ... `debootstrap` is available from the AUR (Archlinux contributed packages), so it's an easy

```
yaourt debootstrap
debootstrap --arch amd64 precise /path/to/chroot/environment
```